# Calculating a certain parameter for an abstract simplicial complex

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, simplicial-complexes

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an abstract simplicial complex on some finite set $\Omega$. I say that a subset $\Lambda\subset\Omega$ is *minimally non-simplicial* if it is not a simplex, but all of its subsets are. Write $h(\mathcal{C})$ for the size of the largest minimally non-simplicial subset of $\Omega$.

I need to calculate $h(\mathcal{C})$ for a particular family of abstract simplicial complexes. I'm wondering if this parameter can be seen somehow using algebraic topology -- via some (co)homology calculation or suchlike. Also, if this parameter has been studied somewhere in the literature, then I would be very interested to know about that.

I apologise if my question is vague/ ill-posed/ inappropriate -- I am not at all an expert on abstract simplicial complexes. For those who are interested, this family of complexes arose when studying some properties of permutation groups.

Comment: A trivial observation: Your parameter is not a topological invariant of the geometric realization of your simplicial complex. So no (co)homology calculation on the space as a whole can give you this parameter. (That doesn't exclude the possibility of getting the parameter by (co)homology calculations on suitable parts of the space, like stars or links.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass, thanks for your comment which is very interesting. However, forgive my total ignorance -- what is trivial for you is not so much for me! Is it easy for you to give an example that illustrates why the parameter is not a topological invariant?

Comment: Consider a 3-point path the complex with three vertices, called 1,2,3, and with edges $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$. So $\{1,2\}$ is a hole of cardinality 2.  Compare with the 2-point path (vertices 1 and 2; edge $\{1,2\}$). It has no hole (of cardinality 2 or otherwise).

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. Did you mean to write that the first example -- a 3-point path -- has a hole equal to $\{1,3\}$? If so, then I get what you are saying, thank you.

Comment: Yes, I meant $\{1,3\}$; sorry for the typo.

Comment: In fact, for any finite simplicial complex $\mathcal{C}$ there is a finite simplicial complex $\mathcal{D}$ with the same geometric realization and with $h(\mathcal{D})=2$. For instance, take $\mathcal{D}$ to be the first barycentric subdivision of $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: @RichardStanley, thank you very much for this. It sounds like a cohomological route towards understanding $H(\mathcal{C})$ is likely to be futile...